# How can I add the %-character in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cms, admin-panel, special-character

I'm trying to add some content in a page in my admin panel, but when I am trying to insert the character `%` this error is displayed:

```
error: error in [unknown object].fireEvent(): event name: tinymceChange error message: URI malformed
```

Is there any way to insert the %-character?

Comment: try `\%` or `&#37;`

Comment: None of those works :(

Comment: You would like to add `%` in content of CMS Page, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly that!

Comment: Do you have WYSWIG enable? What wersion of Magento2 are u using?

Comment: Yes, my WYSIWYG is enable! And my Magento version is the 2.2.0-dev

Comment: I tried as well "%%" the error wasn't displayed but in the page nothing was showed.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I found to do it was creating a 
`<span class="percentage-character"></span>`
in the place that I wanted my %-character and then in the less file do this:

```
.percentage-character:before {
    content: '%';
}
```